# Can you create an superclass of 2 javascript objects

Tags: javascript, oop, interface, superclass

I have a base object class called coretype
e.g.

```
 function coreotype(a,b,c){
    var coreA= a;
    var coreB= b;
    var coreC= c;
    function coreF(){...do something...}
    }
```

I then have a number of modification processes
e.g.

```
function modifyA(m1){var md1 = m1; function mf(){...do something...}}
```

and

```
function modifyA(m1){var md1 = m1; function mf(){...do something...}}
```

I want to create super object classes of the core type and the 1 of the modification processes
to create new object classes
e.g.
typeA which is an object class of coref + modifyA

so that I can define an object by doing something like:

```
var thing1 = new typeA(a,b,c,m1)
```

Is this possible?
Also can these super classes be made using an interface so that I could remove say coreB from the resulting super class or am I just expecting more OOP than javascript can deliver?
I would prefer an answer using javascript over jquery as I would really like to understand how it is being done.
Thanks

Comment: not really a javascript guru, but you might want sometyhing like this `modifyA.prototype = new coreotype;` `modifyB.prototype = new coreotype;`..

Comment: Thanks I got it working using your suggestion
    function coreotype(a,b,c){
    this.coreA= a;
    this.coreB= b;
    this.coreC= c;
    function coreF(){}
    }
    function modifyA(m1){this.md1 = m1; function mf(){}}
    function modifyB(m1){var md1 = m1; function mf(){}}
    var typeA = modifyA
    var typeB = modifyB
    typeA.prototype = new coreotype(1,2,3);
    typeB.prototype = new coreotype(1,2,3);
    var thing1 = new typeA(1);
    var thing2 = new typeB(2);
    alert(thing1.coreB + thing2.coreC);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you really want to understand how this is done.. you must visit -

http://prototypejs.org/learn/class-inheritance

You are free to peek into prototypejs code.

Answer (score 1):

check it out a post by John Resig about more robust Javascript Inheritance and OOP than the simple prototype: http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/